# C# Entity Framework Foreign Key attribute ignored

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have "User" and "Product" entities, product has foreign key to user (UserId -> User). I am trying to add one more foreign key to user in product entity, but getting wrong migration

My updated product entity (example)

```
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AcceptedBy")]
    public int? AcceptedById { get; set; }       
    [ForeignKey("AcceptedById")]
    public User AcceptedBy { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
```

Automaticaly created migration:

```
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Products", "UserId", "dbo.Users");
        AddColumn("dbo.Products", "AcceptedById", c => c.Int());
        AddColumn("dbo.Products", "User_Id", c => c.Int());
        CreateIndex("dbo.Products", "AcceptedById");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Products", "User_Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Products", "AcceptedById", "dbo.Users", "Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Products", "User_Id", "dbo.Users", "Id");
        DropColumn("dbo.Products", "AcceptedByUserId");
```

So my UserId property is ignored

Comment: How did the original migration look like (the one that is changed here)?

Comment: You don't need `ForeignKey` attribute on the navigation properties (`AcceptedBy`, `User`)

Comment: @ Mohamed Ahmed i tried it - not helped

Comment: @ grek40 this is original (without down function)

Comment: @StasPetrov I mean, this migration starts with a `DropForeignKey` so there are definitely previous migrations. Without knowing them its hard to tell the details of what is going on. You can try to create a fresh database and create this model as initial migration - the names should work as expected.

Comment: @ grek40 ofc i can, but what i need to do with exiting db data? Backup-restore?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to many `ForeignKey` data annotations.

```
public int? UserId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public User User { get; set; }

public int? AcceptedById { get; set; }       
[ForeignKey("AcceptedById")] 
public User AcceptedBy { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use fluent API like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
   .HasOptional(h => h.User)
   .WithMany()
   .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.UserId);
```